# Solr - Subtract 2 columns and store the result in the 3rd column

Tags: search, web, solr, compare

I am trying to compare 2 columns in solr. After searching a bit I realised that it is not possible in solr and i need to make a new field and store the result at the time of indexing .

So far i have created a new field called `compare` of type `Boolean` , but i have this question when will the `compare` field get the subtracted value . I know it is at the time of indexing , but i don't know how. I tried putting `column1-column2` as the default field when i was creating the 3rd column , but that didn't work out either.

So any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

EDIT 1:

```js
function processAdd(cmd) {
  doc = wholesale.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
  doc.setField("compare", doc.getFieldValue("min_quanity") > doc.getFieldValue("max_quantity"));
}

function processDelete(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function finish() {
  // no-op
}
```

I made a js file called `updateProcessor.js` and placed the above code inside it and placed the file inside the `conf` folder.

Then i inserted the below code inside the solrconfig.xml

```js
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="calculate-compare">
 
  <processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="script">updateProcessor.js</str>
  </processor>

  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

And then i deleted all the content i had inside the solr table and then re-inserted the XML file . hoping that it would insert content in `compare` field as well . but it didn't work.

Edit 2:
The compare field is of Boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference other fields in your schema definition as far as I know, but you can create [an update request processor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) that does what you want (if you can't do this in your indexing logic - which might be quicker and easier to implement if you already have code in your indexing pipeline).

The [StatelessScriptUpdateProcessor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor) allows you to add a processing step as plain Javascript:

```
<processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="script">updateProcessor.js</str>
</processor>
```

From the example at the wiki linked above, adopted to do what you want in the processAdd method (I've not tested this as I don't have access to a configured Solr collection here):

```
function processAdd(cmd) {
  doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
  doc.setField("compare", doc.getFieldValue("column1") > doc.getFieldValue("column2));
}

function processDelete(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function finish() {
  // no-op
}
```

You then add the chain to your configuration in `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="calculate-compare">
  //
  // your processor definition from above here
  //
  <processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="script">updateProcessor.js</str>
  </processor>

  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

And you tell Solr either to always apply the chain or you give `update.chain=calculate-compare` when indexing.